# How can I get the transaction history of a wallet with more than 1000 transactions/signatures?

Tags: transactions, rust, solana-client

Trying to get the full transaction history of a wallet address, but `get_signatures_for_address()` has a limit of 1000 most recent signatures.

How can I get the entire chain of transactions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fetch the next 1000 transactions after the last transaction returned, you'll need to use the [before filter](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/types/SignaturesForAddressOptions.html), where signature is the last signature on the array returned from get_signatures_for_address().

Here is one way to do it in javascript, where it does three fetches before ending in order to ensure that it doesn't end early due to a failed fetch:

```
const connection = new Connection("https://api.mainnetbeta.solana.com");
let targetAddress = new Publickey("ExamplePublickey");
let signaturesArray = [];
let pullAttempts = 0;
let isEmpty = false;
while (!isEmpty) {
    try {
        const lastSignature = signaturesArray[signaturesArray.length - 1];
        const requestSignatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubkey, {
            before: lastSignature,
            limit: 1000
        });

        if (!(requestSignatures.length > 0)) {
            pullAttempts++;
            if (pullAttempts >= 3) {
                isEmpty = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            const newlyFetchedSignatureArray = requestSignatures.map(data => data.signature);
            signaturesArray = signaturesArray.concat(newlyFetchedSignatureArray);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

If you want to go through manually and/or you're using curl or POST requests, here is the proper formatting for the filter. You'd first do a fetch with no filter, then you would do the following, replacing oldestSignaturesOfLastFetch with the last signaturesat the returned array of signatures. I'd highly recommend you use your own personal RPC:

```
curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/ \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d $'[
    {
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "id": 1,
      "method": "getSignaturesForAddress",
      "params": ["Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111",{"before": "oldestSignaturesOfLastFetch"}]
      }
  ]'
```

Hope this helps, I'd recommend in the future adding what language you're trying to program in, so that answers can be targeted to your language.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `getSignaturesForAddress` template to get signatures (transactions) up to a certain limit (default 100000).

It takes `connection`, `address`, and `maxLength` and returns list of `signatures`

```
 * @param connection A connection to a fullnode JSON RPC endpoint
 * @param address Address of the Signatures to fetch
 * @param maxLength Max Number of Signatures to fetch (default 100,000)
 */
async function getSignaturesForAddress(
  connection: Connection,
  address: PublicKey,
  maxLength?: number,
): Promise<ConfirmedSignatureInfo[]> {
  const signatures = [];
  let _signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(address);
  signatures.push(..._signatures);
  while (true) {
    if (_signatures.length >= 1000 && signatures.length < (maxLength | 100000)) {
      const lastSignature = _signatures[_signatures.length - 1];
      _signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(address, {
        before: lastSignature.signature,
      });
      signatures.push(..._signatures);
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }
  return signatures;
}
```

---

I use this for my Solana Wayback Machine library
https://github.com/vicyyn/wayback-engine/blob/main/src/utils.ts